# shell script, grep in combination with dialog

Tags: bash, shell, grep, dialog

i have a simple question..in regards of dialog and shell scripting..
In order to troubleshoot the problem here the code to isolate the problem

```
    ........
    weekday="Sonntag"
    appointment="1"
    enable="ProgramAktiv"
    RoNo="RO1"
    hour="hour"
    min="min"
    sec="sec"
    program="Program"
    fileName="xxxx.ini"

    #Example: Sonntag_RO1_ProgramAktiv1
    result1=$(grep "$weekday"_"$RoNo"_"$enable$appointment" $fileName)
```

This give me (if i execute the shell script) what i expect

```
    Sonntag_RO1_ProgramAktiv1 = 35
```

Now i used dialog to construct a simple shell dialog.....cool program by the way. Here a function is called..which actually works perfect but....

```
........
entrySelect() {
result1=$(grep "$weekday"_"$RoNo"_"$enable$appointment" $fileName)
    dialog --backtitle "Hygien schedular - Entry select" \
       --colors \
       --msgbox "$result1" 17 60
       #--msgbox $(grep "$weekday"_"$RoNo"_"$enable$appointment" $fileName) 17 60
}
```

This does not work...no text is shown...if i uncomment the line

```
 --msgbox $(grep "$weekday"_"$RoNo"_"$enable$appointment"
```

Then i get the variables.....
What is wrong here...searched the web also piped already the output ...

Help appreciated...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to quote your variable correctly:

```
--msgbox "$(grep "${weekday}_${RoNo}_${enable}${appointment}" $fileName)" 17 60
```

Comment: Isolating the problem

    dialog --backtitle "Isoltated test- Entry select" \--colors \
    --msgbox "$(grep "${weekday}${RoNo}${enable$appointment}" $fileName)" 17 60

shows the box with no content....so we have to investigate further sorry

Comment: didn't you forget the `_` in the variable of the `grep` command?

Comment: in the file.....the entry is now "SonntagRO1ProgramAktiv1 = 35" i remvoed the undelrines...to check if that is the problem....

Comment: Does the `grep` command alone return something? Does the `dialog` command show something?

Comment: "test=${weekday}${RoNo}${enable$appointment}
echo $test " results in ./parse.sh: line 19: ${weekday}${RoNo}${enable$appointment}: bad substitution

Comment: test=$weekday$RoNo$enable$appointment
echo $test results in  SonntagRO1ProgramAktiv1
.....

Comment: grep "${weekday}${RoNo}${enable$appointment}" $fileName results in    ./parse.sh: line 24: ${weekday}${RoNo}${enable$appointment}: bad substitution

Comment: grep $weekday$RoNo$enable$appointment $fileName this works.....SonntagRO1ProgramAktiv1 = 35

Comment: I just updated my answer. I didn't noticed the 4th `$` in the grep command variable...

Answer (score 0):

```
entrySelect() {
dialog --backtitle "test - Entry select" \
--colors \
--msgbox "${weekday}_${RoNo}_${enable}${appointment} \n $(grep "${weekday}_${RoNo}_${enable}${appointment}" $fileName)" 17 60
```

}

works...perfectly...Thanks to @oliv